# sorting xml file using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

how to sort nodes in the xml file and save file in sorted order using linq?

if this is my xml file,

```
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <id>2</id>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <id>3</id>
    <Name>yyy</Name>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

when inserting new node.,
it should be inserted as like this.

```
<Persons>
          <Person>
            <id>1</id>
            <Name>zzz</Name>
          </Person>
          <Person>
            <id>2</id>
            <Name>xxx</Name>
          </Person>
          <Person>
            <id>3</id>
            <Name>yyy</Name>
            </Person>
    </Persons>
```

how to do this using linq?

thank you

Comment: Could you use the answer or is there something unclear? regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following. You should properly use int.TryParse instead of int.Parse and some other checks (for specific elements etc.) if your are not 100% sure of the input. Or check it against a schema.

(I have added a person in the end with id=1. I guess your forgot to add it.)

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Persons>
<Person>
<id>2</id>
<Name>xxx</Name>
</Person>
<Person>
<id>3</id>
<Name>yyy</Name>
</Person>
<Person>
<id>1</id>
<Name>some name</Name>
</Person>
</Persons>");

//By building a new XDocument
var newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Persons",
                from p in doc.Element("Persons").Elements("Person")
                orderby int.Parse(p.Element("id").Value)
                select p));
//or by changing the original XDocument (does not change it where you got it from - a file etc.):

doc.Root.ReplaceAll(from p in doc.Root.Elements("Person")
                    orderby int.Parse(p.Element("id").Value)
                    select p);
```

And to load/save your can use:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("filename"); //Or use a stream etc.
newDoc.Save("filename"); //Or save to a stream etc.
```

You can use:

```
doc.Root
```

instead of:

```
doc.Element("Persons")
```

But again, check the elements if your not 100% sure of the input.